# In a Windows Store app, if I am reading from a folder inside of my LocalFolder regularly, can I keep a static reference?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, storage, winrt-xaml

I have a couple of sub-folders inside of my `LocalFolder` that I use regularly. Can I keep a `static` reference to each of them? Or do I need to call `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync` each time? Is use of the object returned thread-safe? (Not necessarily reading and writing, but file queries)

Answer (score 3):

You sure can, but you need to change things a little.

Look at `FutureAccessList` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx)

> Gets an object that represents a list that an app maintains so that the app can store files and/or locations (like folders) and easily access these items in the future.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

A StorageFolder object is an abstract reference to a folder, which you use in place of a pathname. It's perfectly fine, then, to hold onto those objects throughout an app session. As Jerry noted in another answer, you can use the AccessCache API if you need to retain those objects across app sessions, as that will also preserve access permissions granted through the file picker. This is not necessary, however, for ApplicationData folders as you have inherent permissions to those folders.

I believe the objects are thread-safe as well, as they're coming from WinRT. Know that holding a StorageFolder or StorageFile does not hold anything open--it's when you open a file and obtain a stream that the file is open and might deny other requests to it.